# Buying out of teaching duties vs. all duties using grant money

Tags: funding, teaching

My university (in Europe) is currently reconsidering its **policy regarding professors (assistant through full) buying out of certain duties using funds from research grants**. The new proposal is that the grant money will only be used for buying out of *all of the duties* at once (research, teaching, administration, ... -- all of them). This is in contrast to, say, buying out of teaching alone or out of all duties but research selectively.

The proposal also includes a clause that the **funds obtained** by the university from researchers buying themselves out of duties, specifically the amount corresponding to the research duties, **will be used for "other initiatives and priorities", i.e. not for supporting research directly**.

I see some problems with this policy and wonder if my concerns are justified.

1. If one does not have a grant, one uses, say, 50% of one's time for research as stipulated by the job contract. One gets remunerated for all the work one does, including research (that seems a natural assumption to me). Under the proposed policy, if one has a grant and buys himself/herself out of *all duties*, one will still do research for 50% of the time as before, plus another 50% of the time because of the research grant.
   What is the logic behind buying oneself out of the 50% of the job one will actually be doing anyway?

   Perhaps this could be understandable if the funds were used by the university to employ another person to do *all the duties* of the original job position, including 50% research, but this is not the case according to the proposed policy. The grant money corresponding the 50% of the research work will not be used to fund another researcher but rather to fund other activities. This seems to partly defeat the purpose of the research grant: the money that is earmarked for research is taken by the university and spent on something else.
2. Even though one has to buy oneself out of *all duties*, the university still expects to have its name on the academic production from the grant. So even though the university is not supporting the professor financially, it still wants to receive the benefits that come with achievements in research.

I might be oversimplifying things as I am not very familiar with the system, but the elements indicated above seems problematic to me.

**Questions:** Does this policy proposal sound fine? Is such practice popular in other universities?

Comment: Actually, if the university provides an office and the services of other offices (admissions, internet, etc), then it isn't fair at all to say that the university isn't supporting the professor. This is often considered to be about half of the value of any grant. It can be even more if the university provides basic lab services.

Comment: @Buffy, that does make sense, to a degree. On the other hand, wouldn't it be "fair" for the professor to compensate by grant money any costs to the university incurred by him/her not doing his/her duties, but not beyond? Why should the university suddenly appropriate 50% of the professor's salary just because the professor managed to get grant funding? OK, perhaps it needs to provide office space for the new employee, then subtract that amount. But this does not look like close to 50% of the salary to me.

Comment: Wait, hang on... As a grant holder, one of your duties is to do research related to the grant. So what does "buying out of research duties" even mean? I can't imagine any grant agency allowing anyone to use grant money to buy out of using the grant for its intended purpose.

Comment: @JeffE, Well, you would be buying out of your regular research, not of that specific to the grant, I suppose. So if the grant-specific reseach is not in line with your regular research, the proposed policy makes sense. But since your grant-specific work does not coincide with any of your regular duties, you should simply be taking unpaid leave from the university for the time you are going to do the grant-specific work.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the distinction between "regular research" and "grant-supported research".

Comment: @JeffE, not *grant-supported* but *grant-specific*, though it probably makes little difference here. What I meant is: it may happen that the research topic dictated by the grant is not in line with what is considered appropriate research given your job description. (Such a case has been discussed among the faculty members when considering the new policy proposal, so I mentioned it here for completeness.)

Comment: I am only familiar with a few institutions’ policies on this, but I agree that it is unusual and seems unfair to the departments (and misleading to grant makers) on its face.

Comment: I'd suspect that the school's plan is either to move away from funding research themselves, or to at least make their own funding require a competitive proposal process in the future.

Comment: In my experience in the US, buying out one course of 2+2 teaching load (turning the 2+2 load into a 2+1 load)  often costs 25% of one's annual salary.  Thus this isn't unusual in practice.  If you're going to be replaced by someone who has the same teaching load and salary as you, then that would be a reasonable charge to cover the cost of replacing your teaching.  On the other hand, they might well replace you with a part-time adjunct who will teach the course for less than half of that.

Answer (score 3):

A university doesn't "obtain" funds through buyout -- rather, it frees up salary money that it would otherwise have to spend if the research funds were not in place.

What a university is allowed to do with such funds likely has to do with where the money came from.  In many cases, such funds will be unencumbered, and they can do whatever they want with them.

There are certain kinds of funds that might need to be used to support research, like (in theory) indirect funds from a granting agency.  "Support research" can have broad meaning, such as pay library staff, or keep the rooms where research goes on heated.

I'm not sure I understand the whole situation, the way you've expressed it, but it seems like it gives the university more freedom to creatively release people from responsibilities, and it doesn't set up any alarms for me.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I guess my own concern (being an assoc. prof.) is that this seems "unfair", compared to my impression of the common practice in other places where professors can selectively buy out of teaching but are not forced to buying out of research at the same time. Perhaps my impression is wrong (it is certainly superficial), hence my post.

Comment: @RichardHardy Is this 'research' time that you are buying out of time supported from some general university funds? I wonder if from an administrative standpoint they are thinking of that time as sort of indirect compensation for teaching or doing other university work, and they want to allow well-funded people to buy out all their time but don't want others to pick and choose only the most time-consuming activities for buyout.

Comment: @BryanKrause, the professor just gets a salary and has a set of duties, the main ones being research, teaching and administration. The salary is not explicitly split into the corresponding bits (you would not find such a split in the employment contract), but my understanding is that all of the duties are considered as duties (research is thus just one of them). There is no other compensation or funding aside from the salary that a professor is getting, unless he/she has a grant (or a few). Not sure if I answered your question.

Comment: @RichardHardy Well if in the current system you can buy out your teaching alone, that means the salary must be split into corresponding bits in some way: the amount corresponding to teaching would be the fraction you have to buy out if you wanted to only buy out your teaching. What I meant is that the way the university sees it, if everyone buys out their teaching they need to hire more professors and pay them to teach+the other support. If they only save 30% per professor on the buyouts, they are stuck with another (70% minus grants) to fund.

Comment: @BryanKrause, I guess this is roughly so. The salary is known, the duties are specified in percent, e.g. 50% research, 40% teaching and 10% administration. Then a "fair" system in my understanding would require the grantee to pay as much of grant money to the university as is needed to cover for the substitute teacher (when buying out of the teaching part), even if that is more than 40% of the professor salary.

Comment: That's not fair to the funding agency, which already pays salary, benefits,  and indirects -- so "fair" is relative.

Comment: @RichardHardy Right...or at least some approximation of that. Which seems like it might be roughly what your institution is proposing, by making an 'all-or-none' buyout policy. Not going to weigh in on whether that's truly fair or not; my institution's (US) policy is salary+fringe for your teaching % only. I think here the discussion is more typically about teaching loads vs peer institutions; faculty tend to complain if their expected teaching loads (and therefore possible buyout costs) are greater. A policy requiring buyouts to cover all salary time might be poorly competitive for talent.

Comment: @BryanKrause, could you expand on salary+fringe for teaching % only? Does that mean your salary is paid for teaching alone, and then you do research in your free time as you please (from the salary perspective)?

Comment: @ScottSeidman, let me see if I got you right. If the funding agency want its money to go for research, then the new policy is indeed unfair to the agency. A different policy, one where the professor would not be spending grant money on buying out his/her own research time, would be fairer. It would allow buying out more of non-research (e.g. teaching) time and thus free up more time for research. The university would not gain anything financially (besides the indirect effect of research results), but the researcher would gain more time for research, and more research would be done.

Comment: @RichardHardy No, it's just that each course counts for some % of your salary. To buy it out, you pay the salary plus fringe benefits cost (all your non-salary compensation...in the US a large chunk of that is the portion the university pays for healthcare). The rest of your salary comes from other department slush (mostly indirect funds from grants for my dept) and salary directly from grants. People with more involved administrative positions (research directors and the like that do a lot of compliance work) have a bigger fraction of their salary covered directly by dept funds.

Comment: @RichardHardy. I think you're complicating this.  A grant award is a contract with the funding agency.  The agency pays for a percentage of time, and the investigator spends that time on the project.  Period.  Any other arrangements are between the investigators and their employers. If the employers cannot provide the investigator's hours to the project, they had no business signing the contract.  The institution is obligated.